# How to batch replace part of filenames with the name of their parent directory in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

All of my file names follow this pattern:

```
abc_001.jpg
def_002.jpg
ghi_003.jpg
```

I want to replace the characters before the numbers and the underscore (not necessarily letters) with the name of the directory in which those files are located. Let's say this directory is called 'Pictures'. So, it would be:

```
Pictures_001.jpg
Pictures_002.jpg
Pictures_003.jpg
```

Comment: Downvoted because no attempt was made and sample is not representative of your file configuration.

Comment: Take a look at Perl's standalone `rename` command.

Comment: @Cyrus Can I use variables in place of replacement in s/pattern/replacement/ with rename?

Comment: Yes, see: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: I suggest to update your question with multiple representative examples (with path).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the way this website works, is that you show what you have done, what problem you have, and we give you a hint on how to solve it. You didn't show us anything, so I will give you a starting point, but not the complete solution.

You need to know what to replace: you have given the examples `abc_001` and `def_002`, are you sure that the length of the "to-be-replaced" part always is equal to 3? In that case, you might use the `cut` basic command for deleting this. In other ways, you might use the position of the `'_'` character or you might use `grep -o` for this matter, like in this simple example:

```
ls -ltra | grep -o "_[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg"
```

As far as the current directory is concerned, you might find this, using the environment variable `$PWD` (in case `Pictures` is the deepest subdirectory, you might use `cut`, using `'/'` as a separator and take the last found entry).

Comment: No, it isn't always equal to 3. And using the '_' is also not a good option because there could be other '_' in the filename. What I want is to use the three numbers at the end of the filename along with the underscore and replace what comes before it with whatever I want.

Comment: @Thomas: I added a simple grep example in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I see. But it doesn't help me replace what comes before it.

Comment: The replacement is to be found, using the `$PWD` variable, as I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that part wasn't the problem for me. But what command do I use to put the value of $PWD in place of what I want to replace. I've looked at mmv and rename and sed but I don't know well enough how they work.

Comment: @Thomas "No, it isn't always equal to 3." Yet you put in your question every file with 3. Write a more irregular sample to represent an irregular configuration.

Comment: As already mentioned in previous answers, I have already done such things in the past, and I never work with one script to perform this task. I make sure I get a list of old filenames, a list of new filenames, put them next to each other (use Notepad++ column mode for this), add the `mv` command in front of it and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the current directory with `pwd`, but alse with `echo "${PWD}"`.
With `${x#something}` you can delete `something` from the beginning of the variable. `something` can have wildcards, in which case `#` deletes the smallest, and `##` the largest match.
First try the next command for understanding above explanation:

```
echo "The last part of the current directory `pwd` is ${PWD##*/}"
```

The same construction can be used for cutting the filename, so you can do

```
for f in *_*.jpg; do
   mv "$f" "${PWD##*/}_${f#*_}"
done
```